# property value is not changing in subscribe block in angular4

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am implementing authentication in asp.net core angular application. In my login component I am sending credentials in auth service which returns either true or false. when that returns true it is working fine. But when it is returning false, it is not changing the value of 'invalidLogin' property to true. I have tried this putting outside the subscribe block, only then it works. I have no idea why it is not changing inside subscribe block.
`

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  invalidLogin:boolean | undefined;
  loginCredentials:loginModel={
    email:"",
    password:""
  };

  constructor(private router:Router, private authService:AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invalidLogin=false;
  }

  signIn() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(result=>{
      if(result) this.router.navigate(['/']);
      this.invalidLogin=true;
    });
  }

}
```

`

Comment: it is returning status 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the status code in response, if it's not 200 (success status code range) then it will be handled via error callback like this:

```
.subscribe((data) => {
  // Success case
  console.log(data);
},
(e) => {
  // Error case
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `subscribe` is known as the *next* callback, which is only called if the HTTP request was successful. Because the server is returning a 400 (Bad Request), this is being treated as an error and so your code is not being called.

The *second* argument to `subscribe` is known as the *error* callback: This is called if there is an error. This means you can provide a second argument to be notified if there's an error, like so:

```ts
this.authService.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(
    result => {
        if (result) this.router.navigate(['/']);
        this.invalidLogin = true; // Might not be necessary anymore.
    },
    err => {
        this.invalidLogin = true;
    }
});
```

The Angular [guide](https://angular.io/guide/observables#error-handling) on Observables explains this better than I can:

> Instead, you handle errors by specifying an error callback on the observer. Producing an error also causes the observable to clean up subscriptions and stop producing values. An observable can either produce values (calling the next callback), or it can complete, calling either the complete or error callback.